# RowSorter not set in renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer, rowsorter

I implement icon for sorting column in my jTable.
I have a button for find result and i implement a default sorting when i launch the worker.
Like this :

```
public void refreshStripedViewTable(final List<FlightBox> boxList,
        final List<FlightBoxModel> boxesModels, final String sortBy) {
        if (boxList != null && !boxList.isEmpty()) {
            stripedViewTableModel.setContent(boxesModels);
            tableRenderer.setStripedViewModelList(boxesModels);
            final RowSorter<? extends TableModel> sorter = tableFacade
                .getTooltipsTable().getRowSorter();
            if (sorter != null) {
                List<SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
                javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey sk = new SortKey(getColumnIndex(
                    sortBy, tableFacade.getTooltipsTable()),
                    SortOrder.ASCENDING);
                sortKeys.add(sk);
                sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
                tableFacade.getTooltipsTable().setRowSorter(sorter);
                tableFacade.getTooltipsTable().validate();
                tableFacade.getTooltipsTable().getModelTable()
                    .fireTableDataChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

i add a renderer for setIcon when user click on header on my JTable.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table,
        final Object value, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus,
        final int row, final int column) {
        setIcon(null);
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
            row, column);
        setOpaque(false);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        final RowSorter<?> sorter = table.getRowSorter();
        if (sorter != null) {
            java.util.List<? extends javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = sorter
                .getSortKeys();
            if (sortKeys.size() > 0) {
                javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey sk = sortKeys.get(0);
                // take in account if the user moves the column
                if (column == table.convertColumnIndexToView(sk.getColumn())) {
                    Icon icon = null;
                    if (sk.getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING) {
                        icon = iconService
                            .getRessourceIcon(MediaHmiService.TABLE_SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING);
                    } else if (sk.getSortOrder() == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
                        icon = iconService
                            .getRessourceIcon(MediaHmiService.TABLE_SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING);
                    }
                    setIcon(icon);
                }
            }
        }
        setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        return this;
    }
```

I have a problem when i do this :
 - Found result --> Icon is set on default column sorting OK
 - Click on header for set icon OK
 - Relaunch search --> Not icon is visible.KO
My renderer don't have sortKeys but i set rowSorter in my methode
   refreshStripedViewTable().I don't understand why...

Thanks guys for your help.
Regards.

Comment: why are you re-inventing the wheel? Default sorting takes care of the icon ...

Comment: i just dev this missed code for the good implementation of icons. But if i can do better with normal sorting, tell me more about normal sorting please.

Answer (score 1):

- note there are three types of `SortOrder`
- `ASCENDING`

[image]

- `DESCENDING`

[image]

- `UNSORTED`

[image]

f.i.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class RowSorterDefaults {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JScrollPane pane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    private JTable table = new javax.swing.JTable();

    public RowSorterDefaults() {
        table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {"a", "q", "h", "v"}, {"b", "m", "l", "h"},
                    {"d", "c", "a", "d"}, {"j", "o", "y", "e"}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4"
                }) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            Class[] types = new Class[]{
                String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class
            };

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel()) {
            @Override
            public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
                if (column >= 0 && column < getModelWrapper().getColumnCount() && isSortable(column)) {
                    List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
                    if (!keys.isEmpty()) {
                        SortKey sortKey = keys.get(0);
                        if (sortKey.getColumn()
                                == column && sortKey.getSortOrder()
                                == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {//UNSORTED, ASCENDING
                            setSortKeys(null);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                super.toggleSortOrder(column);
            }
        };
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setDefaultRenderer(RowSorterDefaults.class, new HeaderRenderer(table));
        pane.setViewportView(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        final TableCellRenderer renderer;

        public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        }

        public Icon getIcon(JTable table, int column) {
            for (RowSorter.SortKey sortKey : table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys()) {
                if (sortKey.getColumn() == column) {
                    switch (sortKey.getSortOrder()) {
                        case ASCENDING:
                            return (UIManager.getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon"));
                        case DESCENDING:
                            return (UIManager.getIcon("Table.descendingSortIcon"));
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RowSorterDefaults();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a problem when i do this : - Found result --> Icon is set on
>   default column sorting OK - Click on header for set icon OK - Relaunch
>   search --> Not icon is visible.KO My renderer don't have sortKeys but
>   i set rowSorter in my methode refreshStripedViewTable().I don't
>   understand why...

Icon are added as defaults to UIManager, then all JTables in current JVM has the same Icons

- `ASCENDING`

[image]

- `DESCENDING`

[image]

- `UNSORTED`

[image]

f.i.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class RowSorterCustom {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JScrollPane pane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    private JTable table = new javax.swing.JTable();

    public RowSorterCustom() {
        table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {"a", "q", "h", "v"}, {"b", "m", "l", "h"},
                    {"d", "c", "a", "d"}, {"j", "o", "y", "e"}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4"
                }) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            Class[] types = new Class[]{
                String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class
            };

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel()) {
            @Override
            public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
                if (column >= 0 && column < getModelWrapper().getColumnCount() && isSortable(column)) {
                    List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
                    if (!keys.isEmpty()) {
                        SortKey sortKey = keys.get(0);
                        if (sortKey.getColumn()
                                == column && sortKey.getSortOrder()
                                == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {//UNSORTED, ASCENDING
                            setSortKeys(null);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                super.toggleSortOrder(column);
            }
        };
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        pane.setViewportView(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class BevelArrowIcon implements Icon {

        public static final int UP = 0;         // direction
        public static final int DOWN = 1;
        private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 11;
        private Color edge1;
        private Color edge2;
        private Color fill;
        private int size;
        private int direction;

        public BevelArrowIcon(int direction, boolean isRaisedView, boolean isPressedView) {
            if (isRaisedView) {
                if (isPressedView) {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlLtHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlDkShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                } else {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("control"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                }
            } else {
                if (isPressedView) {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlDkShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlLtHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                } else {
                    init(UIManager.getColor("controlShadow"),
                            UIManager.getColor("controlHighlight"),
                            UIManager.getColor("control"),
                            DEFAULT_SIZE, direction);
                }
            }
        }

        public BevelArrowIcon(Color edge1, Color edge2, Color fill, int size, int direction) {
            init(edge1, edge2, fill, size, direction);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            switch (direction) {
                case DOWN:
                    drawDownArrow(g, x, y);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    drawUpArrow(g, x, y);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return size;
        }

        private void init(Color edge1, Color edge2, Color fill, int size, int direction) {
            edge1 = Color.red;
            edge2 = Color.blue;
            this.edge1 = edge1;
            this.edge2 = edge2;
            this.fill = fill;
            this.size = size;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        private void drawDownArrow(Graphics g, int xo, int yo) {
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo, xo + size - 1, yo);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + 1, xo + size - 3, yo + 1);
            g.setColor(edge2);
            g.drawLine(xo + size - 2, yo + 1, xo + size - 1, yo + 1);
            int x = xo + 1;
            int y = yo + 2;
            int dx = size - 6;
            while (y + 1 < yo + size) {
                g.setColor(edge1);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + 1, y);
                g.drawLine(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                if (0 < dx) {
                    g.setColor(fill);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y, x + 1 + dx, y);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y + 1, x + 1 + dx, y + 1);
                }
                g.setColor(edge2);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y, x + dx + 3, y);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y + 1, x + dx + 3, y + 1);
                x += 1;
                y += 2;
                dx -= 2;
            }
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo + (size / 2), yo + size - 1, xo + (size / 2), yo + size - 1);
        }

        private void drawUpArrow(Graphics g, int xo, int yo) {
            g.setColor(edge1);
            int x = xo + (size / 2);
            g.drawLine(x, yo, x, yo);
            x--;
            int y = yo + 1;
            int dx = 0;
            while (y + 3 < yo + size) {
                g.setColor(edge1);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + 1, y);
                g.drawLine(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                if (0 < dx) {
                    g.setColor(fill);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y, x + 1 + dx, y);
                    g.drawLine(x + 2, y + 1, x + 1 + dx, y + 1);
                }
                g.setColor(edge2);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y, x + dx + 3, y);
                g.drawLine(x + dx + 2, y + 1, x + dx + 3, y + 1);
                x -= 1;
                y += 2;
                dx += 2;
            }
            g.setColor(edge1);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + size - 3, xo + 1, yo + size - 3);
            g.setColor(edge2);
            g.drawLine(xo + 2, yo + size - 2, xo + size - 1, yo + size - 2);
            g.drawLine(xo, yo + size - 1, xo + size, yo + size - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.ascendingSortIcon", new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.UP, false, false));
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.descendingSortIcon", new BevelArrowIcon(BevelArrowIcon.DOWN, false, false));
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RowSorterCustom();
            }
        });
    }
}
```