# How Can I Maintain User-Specified Table Row Sorting in a JTable after fireTableStructureChanged?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

The method `fireTableStructureChanged()` re-draws the whole JTable from scratch. It is well known that the user specified columns widths and user specified row sorting (when the user clicks on one of the column's header) will be lost.

Is there a way to store the customized sorting and retrieve it back after calling `fireTableStructureChanged()`? 
May be the methods `convertRowIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToView` can help...

Or is there an alternative way to redraw the whole table (after changing the row count) with keeping the sorting?

Here is short example of my experiment to add/remove some rows:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class Table extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTable table;

    private String[][] tableData = {{"a", "5"},
                                    {"b", "4"},
                                    {"c", "9"},
                                    {"d", "2"},
                                    {"e", "1"},
                                    {"f", "7"},
                                    {"g", "3"},
                                    {"h", "8"},
                                    {"i", "6"}};

    private String[] columns = {"A", "B"};

    public Table() {
        MyTableModel mtm = new MyTableModel(tableData, columns);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table = new JTable(mtm);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);                     

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 150));
        this.add(scrollpane);
        this.setLocation(300, 100);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();

        //Trying to add and remove some rows:
        mtm.addRow(new Object[]{"new 1", "new 2"});
        mtm.removeRow(2);
        mtm.removeRow(3);
        table.addNotify();
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String[][] tableData;

        private String[] columns;

        public MyTableModel(String[][] tableData, String[] columns) {
            this.tableData = tableData;
            this.columns = columns;
        }

        public void addRow(Object newRow) {
             fireTableRowsInserted(2, 2);
        }

        public void removeRow(int row) {
            fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return tableData.length;
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columns[column];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return tableData[row][col];
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            String oldValue = (String) tableData[row][col];
            if(oldValue.equals((String)value)) {
                return;
            }
            tableData[row][col] = value.toString();
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Table();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, yes/no, no, yes, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: @mKorbel I added a stand alone program code that illustrates my problem.

Comment: [btw view to model isn't clear described in API(inherits from DefaultRowSorter<M,I>)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html), note SortKey has tree states [SortOrder.DESCENDING, UNSORTED, ASCENDING](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18530099/714968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [AbstractTableModel#fireTableStructureChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged%28%29) javadoc:

> Notifies all listeners that the table's structure has changed. The
>   number of columns in the table, and the names and types of the new
>   columns may be different from the previous state. If the `JTable`
>   receives this event and its autoCreateColumnsFromModel flag is set it
>   discards any table columns that it had and reallocates default columns
>   in the order they appear in the model. This is the same as calling
>   `setModel(TableModel)` on the `JTable`.

So if you call this method then doesn't make sense keep columns width (because may have changed) nor row sorting or filtering (also data may have changed).

> *Or is there an alternative way to redraw the whole table (after changing the row count) with keeping the sorting?*

If you want to update your table data on a row insert/delete, then you need to provide such methods in your table model and notify [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) in such events:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    ...
    public void addRow(Object newRow) {
        // add row to underlying data structure here
         fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    public void remove(Object rowToBeDeleted) {
        // remove row from the underlying data structure here
        fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }
    ...
}
```

See [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) API:

- [fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow,int lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29)
- [fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)

In this way columns width and rows sorting and filtering will remain unaltered.